# Google Documents: set heading as defined in current document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm writing a script that picks the paragraph where the cursor is contained, set the text to uppercase and change the paragraph heading to HEADING1. 
However, the paragraph is set to the 'global' HEADING1, not to HEADING1 as it is defined in the current document. Here is the code.

```
function SetSceneHeading() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var element = cursor.getElement();
  var paragraph = [];
  if (element.getType() != 'PARAGRAPH') {
    paragraph = element.getParent().asParagraph();
  }
  else paragraph = element.asParagraph();
  var txt = paragraph.getText();
  var TXT = txt.toUpperCase();
  paragraph.setText(TXT);
  paragraph.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
}
```

Is there a way to set a paragraph to the 'current' HEADING1? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need heading attribute for other purposes than visual highlight?  I mean to create a TOC or something? I'm asking this because 'normal' attributes are perfectly useable and don't have this inherent limitation... so it could be a possible workaround.

Comment: I'm trying to make a scriptwriting template and for various reasons I prefer to have HEADING1 as a SceneHeading style. As a workaround, I can probably set the paragraph to HEADING1 and then set the attributes according to the custom HEADING1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that this won't be possible for now, there is an open issue that I think is relevant : [issue 2373](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2373) (status acknowledged) , you could star it to get informed of any enhancement.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaroud to set a paragraph to a user defined heading. Basically, you first set the heading using setHeading(), then you set to "null" the attributes that the previous operation messed up. This way the paragraph is set according to the user defined heading.

```
 function MyFunction ()
 var paragraph = ....
 paragraph.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
 paragraph.setAttributes(ResetAttributes());


 function ResetAttributes() {
 var style = {};
 style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = null;
 style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = null;
 style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = null;
 style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] = null;
 return style;
 }
```

I made a few tests, FONT_SIZE BOLD SPACING_BEFORE SPACING_AFTER seem to be the attributes that need to be reset. They may be more, according to the cases.

Comment: Nice workaround!  Thank you for sharing, please consider posting it on the issue 2373 comments.